# Pony Orm - 'Insert if not exists' statement

Tags: python, ponyorm

I'm wondering how to run a query that inserts an item into a database only if it doesn't already exist. I'm using json for the entity, so they look like this:

```python
class Person(db.Entity):
    json = Required(Json)

name = "Alice"

if not Person.exists(lambda person: person['name'] == name):
    Person(json={'name': name, """ lots more fields """})
```

But this seems to perform two queries, which slows the operation down. Ideally I want something like

```python
Person.insert_if_not_exists(json={...})
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why are you inserting a json object into the database?

Comment: Using a mixin does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797438/1279003

Answer (score 1):

At this moment Pony does not support `get_or_create` as a single command, we plan to add it later

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to catch the duplicate exception during insertion as described here:

```
    try:
        with pony.orm.db_session:
            table(**row)
    except pony.orm.core.TransactionIntegrityError as e:
        if 'UNIQUE constraint failed' not in unicode(e):
            # Ignore duplicate
        else:
            raise
```